# Eigenvalues of $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ in $C^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

Consider the eigenvalue problem
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
  \Phi \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R}) \ \text{and bounded }\\
 -\Phi^{''}(x)=\lambda\Phi(x), \ x\in \mathbb{R}.
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

and assume that the solution is given by $\Phi(x)=Ae^{i\sqrt{\lambda}x}+Be^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}x}$.

How can one prove that $\lambda$ is real and not negative?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is not a non-negative real number, then the exponents have a non-zero real part. This violates the condition that $\Phi$ be bounded.

Comment: @Wmmoreno: Kindly change the spelling to "analysis". :)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII ok tkz ...XD

Comment: @brom I don't understand very well... Can you answer the question plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is not true that $\lambda \geq 0$, then $\operatorname{Im} \sqrt{\lambda} \neq 0$, i.e. $\sqrt{\lambda} = a + ib$ with $b \neq 0$. Thus 
$$C\exp(i \sqrt{\lambda} x) = C \exp(iax)\exp(-bx)$$
is unbounded as $x \to \infty$ or as $x \to -\infty$ depending on the sign of $b$. Thus if a solution of the form you propose is bounded, then either $\lambda \geq 0$ or $A = B = 0$.

(Note that it is not possible for one term to sufficiently cancel out the other unless $b = -b$ i.e. $\lambda \geq 0$).

Answer (score 0):

If $\lambda<0,$ then $\sqrt{\lambda}=i \Im{\sqrt{\lambda}} + \Re{\sqrt{\lambda}},$ then $\Phi(x)=Ae^{i\sqrt{\lambda}x}+Be^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}x} $ can be written by $\Phi(x)=Ae^{-\Im{\sqrt{\lambda}}x + i\Re{\sqrt{\lambda}}x }+B e^{-\Im{\sqrt{\lambda}} x+ i\Re{\sqrt{\lambda}}x }.$ But $e^{-\Im{\sqrt{\lambda}}x}$ is not bounded. Thus, $\lambda$ is not negative.

Comment: but $\lambda$ could be a complex numerb

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to exclude this case. But if $\Phi\in H^1(\mathbb{R}),$ then you can multiply $\bar{\Phi}$ to both side and integrate to exclude this case.

Comment: you said, I need to change the space